# What to change in secure connection to set the styles?

Tags: html, css

I'm developing a website and get the webpage [linked here](https://secure.nesinvakfi.org/nesinyayinevi/test.html). The problem is that the webpage is not rendered with the styles.

[image]

But when I open its source and copy it to a new file on my desktop, the style is now rendered approppriately. I couldn't figure out why it doesn't work on the secure connection. Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: may be if you are using external css and url starting with http:// instead of https://

Comment: http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/OrwppKWbKnc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From my browser's error console:

> [blocked] The page at '`https://secure.nesinvakfi.org/nesinyayinevi/test.html`' was loaded over HTTPS, but ran insecure content from '`http://www.nesinyayinevi.com/bootstrap/css/nybs.css`': this content should also be loaded over HTTPS.

If you are going to use HTTPS, then use it everywhere in the page. Don't inject insecure content into the page, it makes using HTTPS pointless.

Answer (score 1):

Open the console to see all sorts of errors:

- The page at 'https://secure.nesinvakfi.org/nesinyayinevi/test.html' was loaded over HTTPS, but displayed insecure content from 'http://www.nesinyayinevi.com/bootstrap/img/grid-18px-masked.png': this content should also be loaded over HTTPS.
- Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) https://secure.nesinvakfi.org/nesinyayinevi/resimler/english.jpg

In the first case, the scheme of the requested URL and the scheme of included resources need to match.  Use `https://www.nesinyayinevi.com`  You could also use `//www` to have the scheme automatically match that of the requested page, but since this is `secure.nesinvakfi` I have to imagine that it's going to be https.

If you can't use `https` for `nesinyayinevi.com`, then you're going to have to copy the resources over or otherwise proxy them through https.

As for the 404 errors, it seems like you are using a relative path like `bootstrap/js`, but these are for the wrong domain.  You need to use the domain absolute path of `https://nesinyayinevi.com` like you are doing for the CSS files.